# VueJs how to access object items in v-for

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm getting the following:

[image]

[image]

Vue template code:

```
<select class="form-select" v-model="post_format.wpml_language">

<option  v-for="(lang, index) in wpml_languages" :value="lang">{{lang}} {{index}}</option>

</select>
```

What I want; I want the value attribute of the option element to be the language code (en/es) and the text displayed to be the Language name

I'm not sure how to access the object in the vue code for it to display in the way I want. I've tried:

```
<select class="form-select" v-model="post_format.wpml_language">
<option  v-for="(lang, index) in wpml_languages" :value="lang[index]">{{lang[index]}}</option> 
</select>
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to modify your object so that your code and language are separate values.

```
this.languages.filter(lang =>{
  var code = Object.keys(lang)[0];
  lang.code = code;
  lang.value = lang[code];
});
```

This will make your code more readable. [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-franklin-sf2q6) link for your reference.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't want `lang[index]`, because you have nested objects. 
In this instance, the actual loop index is not useful. For each member of 'lang', you most likely want the key to be your option value ("en") and the value to be the printed text ("English"). While the following is not the cleanest option, it will work:

```
<select class="form-select" v-model="post_format.wpml_language">
    <option  v-for="(lang, index) in wpml_languages" :value="Object.keys(lang)[0]">
        {{ lang[0] }}
    </option> 
</select>
```

Comment: The value works but the text for the option is blank